# Disable dropdown list when radiobutton is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

My web form has 2 controls, [drpBloodType and rbUnknownBloodType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v2fw.png).

I need to disable the list whenever the button is checked.
I tried:

```
protected void rbUnknownBloodType_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drpBloodType.Enabled = false;
}
```

and

```
<script>
   $(function () {
      $('#rbUnknownBloodType').change(function () {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#drpBloodType').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         } else {
         $('#drpBloodType').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

but neither worked.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: It's possible that your jQuery selector doesn't find `$('#rbUnknownBloodType')` because ASP.NET adds something like `ContentPlaceHolder1_` to button's ID. Check your generated HTML. And you should use a checkbox so user can also uncheck the `unknown` field.

Comment: NVM, I just had to enable AutoPostBack. I am dumb!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `change` event handler to all radio-buttons in the same group as `'#rbUnknownBloodType'`. The change event on a radio-button does not fire when the radio-button becomes unchecked - the line

```
$('#drpBloodType').removeAttr('disabled');
```

in your code will never execute.

```js
$(".test").change(function(){
  console.log(this.value, this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" type="radio" name="test" value="1"/>
<input class="test" type="radio" name="test" value="2"/>
```

Hm, I looked at the picture in your question. Will a checkbox be better there?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following aspx markup you can do the following in code-behind. Note the usage of `AutoPostBack="true"` on the CheckBox.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="BloodType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="A+" Value="A+"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="A-" Value="A-"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B+" Value="B+"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B-" Value="B-"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="O+" Value="O+"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="O-" Value="O-"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="AB+" Value="AB+"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="AB-" Value="AB-"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="UnknownBloodType" OnCheckedChanged="UnknownBloodType_CheckedChanged" 
  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Code behind.

```
protected void UnknownBloodType_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set the dll to default
    BloodType.SelectedValue = "";

    //cast the sender back to a checkbox and disable the dll based on it's checked status
    BloodType.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
}
```

Or the jquery solution. This saves a PostBack, but it loses the disabled state after a PostBack. `%= UnknownBloodType.ClientID %>` only works on the aspx page itself. If you do not want to use it then look into `ClientIdMode=Static`

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= UnknownBloodType.ClientID %>').change(function () {
            var dll = $('#<%= BloodType.ClientID %>');
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                dll.val('');
                dll.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                dll.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```